# Spellcasting with focus and shield

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, shield

Warlock with Wand +1 and shield (hexblade, he has proficiency in shields)

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell's material components—or to hold a spellcasting focus—but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components (PHB p.203)

Can he cast spells that need S component but not M? (without warcaster feat)

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102252/can-a-multiclass-cleric-warlock-hold-a-holy-shield-and-an-arcane-staff-and-still

Answer (score 2):

### RAW. It would appear not.

According to the Sage Advice Compendium referenced in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105480/casting-a-somatic-non-material-spell-while-holding-a-focus) state that you can only use the hand holding your focus if the spell requires a non-costly material component.

This seems to make no sense and is likely one of those rulings from the devs that I will ignore as illogical. There is seemingly no difference between somatic components between a spell that requires material components and one that doesn't. There is nothing breaking in this decision at all. Most of us hand waive over the free hand to a certain extent anyway. The SA ruling seems to be overly punishing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87856/discussion-on-answer-by-slagmoth-spellcasting-with-focus-and-shield).

Answer (score 1):

**In short: No you can't, you still need that free hand**

When casting spells you typically need 1, 2 or all 3 types of component: Material, Somatic, and Verbal. Spells that require a verbal component only require the use of your mouth, however Somatic and Material components require a free hand:

PHB 203

> Somatic (S)
>
> Spellcasting gestures might include a forceful gesticulation or an
>   intricate set of gestures. If a spell requires a somatic component,
>   the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these
>   gestures.
>
> Material (M)
>
> ….. A spellcaster must have a hand free to access these components,
>   but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic
>   components.

A shield does take the use of one of your hands as does the Hexblade. For Hexblade Warlocks, the Hexblade can't be used a spellcasting focus nor is any indication given that you can perform Somatic components while holding the Hexblade in your hand. Looking into Warlocks further I found no evocations or class abilities that would allow any similar effect to what you are looking for.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88019/discussion-on-answer-by-kdodge-spellcasting-with-focus-and-shield).