# Can an Arcane Firearm staff receive the d8 bonus when casting any of the blade cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, artificer

Can an [artillerist](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Artillerist)'s Arcane Firearm staff receive the d8 bonus when casting any of the blade cantrips? Since the staff can be both an arcane focus and can supposedly be [used as a melee weapon.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46704/can-the-arcane-druidic-focus-staff-double-as-quarterstaff)

Specifically Booming Blade and/or Greenflame Blade

Additionally, if yes, which damage does the d8 add to? The bludgeoning from the staff, or the secondary damage types?

Answer (score 6):

#### Yes, this works.

There is no reason the Arcane Firearm feature would not apply to *booming blade* or *green flame blade* - they are artificer spells, and the feature triggers when:

> you cast an artificer spell through the firearm.

Both the bludgeoning damage and the thunder/fire damage count as damage rolls for the spell, so you can choose which gets the d8 from Arcane Firearm.