# How do the actions work out when sheathing/drawing weapon and then casting a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, actions, spellcasting, action-economy

My character is a **Warlock/Fighter** with **two-weapons fighting** speciality. 
I'm kinda confused with 2 weapons and the spellcasting. All at the same time.
So I have the following scenario, please, correct me:

1. Enter the battle holding 2 weapons.
2. Sheath one weapon as free action (PHB 190)...
3. ...and cast a spell with S or S/M components using action (or bonus action) with one empty hand.
4. And finally draw that weapon back. (I'm 666% sure this is wrong, but cannot figure our why)

So what is wrong and what is right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything about this is correct until #4. The problem is that you only get 1 free interaction with an object on your turn. Thus you can *either* sheathe or draw a weapon on your turn.

You have 2 options:

1. Drop the weapon at 2 instead of sheathing it. Dropping it does not count against your object interaction, but picking it up does.
2. Spend every other turn with only one weapon. Obviously this means you don't get the passive benefits from TWF (namely the AC boost if you take Dual Wielder) every other turn.

Overall, 1 is probably the better option, even if it seems kind of cheapy, it's the proper RAW scenario for this type of action.

Comment: Mmmm... reading PHB page 190, under Movement and Position there is a note box titled Interacting with Objects Around You.  In it, is says "Here are a few examples of the sort of things you can do in tandem with your movement *AND* action:"  This would tell me I can draw or sheathe a sword twice.  So turn order would be: 1 - Movement, sheathe, 2 - Action, cast spell and then draw, 3 - bonus action.  I don't see anywhere where it states you can only do it on either movement or action.  This says "and".  Unless the "and" is grouping them, which as written is misleading and confusing.

Comment: @Kyaaadaa: See ["Other Activity on Your Turn"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn): "You can also interact with **one** object or feature of the environment for free, during **either** your move or your action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe, or you could draw your weapon as part of the same action you use to attack. **If you want to interact with a second object, you need to use your action.** Some magic items and other special objects always require an action to use, as stated in their descriptions."