# Volume of Darkness (spell) interaction with Enlarge creature

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size, area-of-effect

If I am [enlarged](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce), and subsequently cast [darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) on my weapon does the volume that darkness covers expand from my character or only one square that my character occupies?

If the latter, how do I keep track of which square my weapon is in?

Comment: Related: [Can Darkness be cast on a part of an object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125836)

Comment: Ah thank you! that is also quite helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It emanates from the corner of a square you chose

[Darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) is emanating from a point, [which can be on an object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125836) and moves with the object:

> Magical darkness **spreads from a point you choose** within range  to fill a 15-foot-radius sphere (...) If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the darkness emanates from the object and moves with it.

The DMG explains on page 251 how to place the point of origin when you are using a grid:

> The area of effect of a spell, monster ability, or other
> feature must be translated onto squares or hexes to
> determine which potential targets are in the area and
> which aren't. **Choose an intersection of squares or hexes as the
> point of origin of an area of effect**, then follow its rules
> as normal. If an area of effect is circular and covers at
> least half a square, it affects that square.

So you choose an intersection of squares of the space the object is in as the point of origin. If you are large, this could be any of corners of the four squares that make up the space you occupy.

For darkness, you can move the object and the darkness sphere will move with it. You probably can choose a new intersection if you move the object to another square, or, if you move yourself you could keep it on the same relative intersection of your space for ease of use, while you move around.

If you intentionally manipulate the object to move the darkness around, your DM might call for an Object Interaction action, one of which is free one per round (p. 196 PHB).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

So I'm supposed to have been choosing just an intersection for the other targeting mode as well? Good to know

Comment: Yes, it is emanating from a point either way, see the other answer Thomas linked to for an in-depth explanation for that.